# SQL Why do I have to use GroupBy with OrderBy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

Hi guys I have a range of different football match data.

What I am trying to do is take an average and sum of a number of games for a particular league. I am ordering by date to get the latest matches and then selecting Top (X) as the user defines how many they want to select.

However I don't understand why I have to use GroupBy as I have nothing to group with an just want the average and sum of all of them.

My query is as follows,

> ```
> ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[isp_CompetitionSummary_GenerateByMatches]
> @CompetitionId varchar(4),
> @Matches int
> AS
> BEGIN
> SELECT TOP (@Matches)
> [Date],
> @CompetitionId AS CompetitionId,
> Sum(HomeGoals) AS HomeGoals,
> Sum(AwayGoals) AS AwayGoals,
> Sum(HalfTimeHomeGoals) AS HalfTimeHomeGoals,
> Sum(HalfTimeAwayGoals) AS HalfTimeAwayGoals,
> Sum(HomeTeamCorners) AS HomeCorners,
> Sum(AwayTeamCorners) AS AwayCorners,
> Sum(HomeTeamFouls) AS HomeFouls,
> Sum(AwayTeamFouls) AS AwayFouls,
> Sum(HomeTeamYellows) AS HomeYellows,
> Sum(AwayTeamYellows) AS AwayYellows,
> Sum(HomeTeamReds) AS HomeReds,
> Sum(AwayTeamReds) AS AwayReds,
> AVG(CAST(HomeGoals AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeGoals,
> AVG(CAST(AwayGoals AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayGoals,
> AVG(CAST(HalfTimeHomeGoals AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHalfTimeHomeGoals,
> AVG(CAST(HalfTimeAwayGoals AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHalfTimeAwayGoals,
> AVG(CAST(HomeTeamCorners AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeCorners,
> AVG(CAST(AwayTeamCorners AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayCorners,
> AVG(CAST(HomeTeamFouls AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeFouls,
> AVG(CAST(AwayTeamFouls AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayFouls,
> AVG(CAST(HomeTeamYellows AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeYellows,
> AVG(CAST(AwayTeamYellows AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayYellows,
> AVG(CAST(HomeTeamReds AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeReds,
> AVG(CAST(AwayTeamReds AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayReds
> FROM dbo.Match
> INNER JOIN dbo.MatchDetail ON dbo.Match.Id = dbo.MatchDetail.MatchId
> WHERE Div = @CompetitionId
> GROUP BY [Date]
> ORDER BY [Date] DESC
> ```

Comment: Unless all matches are on the same date, you're not computing average or sum of all of them; you're computing the average/sum for all of the matches on each given date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand what I am doing I guess I worded my question wrong. How would I take the averages of everything? I always get "Column 'dbo.Match.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: If you wanted the average & sum of everything, where not everything has the same date, what date would you expect to display?

Comment: I do not need the date at all to show I have removed this from the select, I just need get the average and sums of the last X games the order by date was to ensure these are the latest matches

Comment: Good, so by not selecting the date, you don't have to group by it. Now to get the last 10 games only, add the necessary criteria to your WHERE clause (I can't say exactly what that criteria is because I don't have a list of all your columns or know how the data is stored).

Comment: In effect the aggregate function is both grouping AND summing. If you wanted to see the last 4 games that happened and the home goals were 1,0,0,1 then the single row for that date sums to 2. If you didn't have SUM but did group then it gives you distinct values of 1,0 as the home goals. If you don't group by the home goals column it doesn't consider that column to be grouped as a sum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TOP (@Matches)` won't limit the data that you work on, it will only limit the result. You will get the sums and averages of all data, grouped by date, and then limited to the last `@Matches` dates.

Limit the data in a subquery first, then you can get the sums and averages of those matches.

Notice that the `[Date]` is removed from the select. If you want to select a date, then you have to decide which date to get, for example the latest date using `MAX([Date])`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[isp_CompetitionSummary_GenerateByMatches]
@CompetitionId varchar(4),
@Matches int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
@CompetitionId AS CompetitionId,
Sum(HomeGoals) AS HomeGoals,
Sum(AwayGoals) AS AwayGoals,
Sum(HalfTimeHomeGoals) AS HalfTimeHomeGoals,
Sum(HalfTimeAwayGoals) AS HalfTimeAwayGoals,
Sum(HomeTeamCorners) AS HomeCorners,
Sum(AwayTeamCorners) AS AwayCorners,
Sum(HomeTeamFouls) AS HomeFouls,
Sum(AwayTeamFouls) AS AwayFouls,
Sum(HomeTeamYellows) AS HomeYellows,
Sum(AwayTeamYellows) AS AwayYellows,
Sum(HomeTeamReds) AS HomeReds,
Sum(AwayTeamReds) AS AwayReds,
AVG(CAST(HomeGoals AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeGoals,
AVG(CAST(AwayGoals AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayGoals,
AVG(CAST(HalfTimeHomeGoals AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHalfTimeHomeGoals,
AVG(CAST(HalfTimeAwayGoals AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHalfTimeAwayGoals,
AVG(CAST(HomeTeamCorners AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeCorners,
AVG(CAST(AwayTeamCorners AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayCorners,
AVG(CAST(HomeTeamFouls AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeFouls,
AVG(CAST(AwayTeamFouls AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayFouls,
AVG(CAST(HomeTeamYellows AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeYellows,
AVG(CAST(AwayTeamYellows AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayYellows,
AVG(CAST(HomeTeamReds AS FLOAT)) AS AvgHomeReds,
AVG(CAST(AwayTeamReds AS FLOAT)) AS AvgAwayReds
FROM (
  SELECT TOP (@Matches) *
  FROM dbo.Match
  INNER JOIN dbo.MatchDetail ON dbo.Match.Id = dbo.MatchDetail.MatchId
  WHERE Div = @CompetitionId
  ORDER BY [Date] DESC
) x
```

Note: When you use aggregates the query is always grouped. By omiting the `GROUP BY` and still using aggregates in the query, the entire set will be a single group.

Answer (score 0):

You want the sum and averages for each date. Ie. "grouped by" date. That is exactly what you want, so you do have to group by date.

In fact, any time you use an aggregate function in the select list, if you are also selecting a field without using an aggregate, you do have to group by those non-aggregate columns, because that is in fact what you are doing.

You're selecting many SUMs and averages PER DATE (not the whole table overall). Thus, you are grouping.

Also it has nothing to do with the fact that you are using the ORDER BY. The GROUP BY is required because you are using aggregate functions with some fields while also selecting non-aggregate columns.

Comment: Thanks, so how would I go about taking the averages and sums of everything I have selected and not group by date?

Comment: If you really don't want to group by date, then don't select the date field. If you don't select the date field, you don't have to group. However, that will calculate the sums and averages across the WHOLE TABLE (not for each date on the table).

Comment: I do not need the date at all to show I have removed this from the select, I just need get the average and sums of the last X games the order by date was to ensure these are the latest matches